# how do i connect midi to bitwig in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: midi

I'm having trouble connecting midi to bitwig. I can see my midi devices in carla but there are no midi inputs into bitwig studio. When I plug a new device in I get a midi error in bitwig that says "device or resource busy". I can connect midi to yoshimi because it shows up in carla with a red "midi in". Any idea how to get a red "midi in" to show up on bitwig studio in carla?

Comment: Might be better to try and get help from the company that makes Carla.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwig don't share devices.

You have to end all midi clients and stop a2jmidid

Comment: this worked. Thank you!